# save substring next to a repeated pattern (bash)

Tags: bash

My file looks like this:

```
__1 AAA =====
__2 BBB =====
__3 CCC =====
_10 DDD =====
_11 BBB =====
_14 EEE =====
_15 BBB =====
_20 CCC =====
```

Underlines are trying to denote spaces (blanks) in my file.

Because there are three lines with the pattern `BBB`, and two with the pattern `CCC` I need to save the numbers accompanying them at their left (if possible saving them in different variables), but just the highest numbers (it is, not the lower). Therefore, the numbers would be (output of my file):

```
11
15
20
```

(notice that for all the others there are just one register, so I do not need any number)

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: BBB has a `15`, so it looks like the `11` shouldn't be printed at all; if we're filtering only for keys mentioned at least twice, and returning the highest input for each, I see correct output as just `15` `20`.

Comment: I  am leaving out the number associated with DDD because there a unique register (non repeated)

Comment: BTW, while I answered this because it was somewhat interesting, usually we do ask that a question be isolated to be about a specific issue you're having with the language (a library, etc), not just a specification for a program you want written. Without isolating a specific problem encountered in the process of writing the specified program (and building a [mcve] that resolves around only that issue), a question is often eligible to be closed as "too broad".

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
case $BASH_VERSION in ''|[123].*) echo "ERROR: Bash 4.0 required" >&2; exit 1;; esac

declare -A highest=( ) count=( )
while read -r num pat _; do : num="$num" pat="$pat"
  (( ++count[$pat] ))
  if [[ -z ${highest[$pat]} ]] || (( num > ${highest[$pat]} )); then
    highest[$pat]=$num
  fi
done

readarray -t sorted_keys < <(printf '%s\n' "${!highest[@]}" | sort)

for key in "${sorted_keys[@]}"; do : key="$key"
  if (( ${count[$key]} > 1 )); then
    printf '%s\n' "${highest[$key]}"
  fi
done
```

Comment: If you were wondering why Bash 4.0 is needed, the answer is _Associative Arrays_ which are used here and declared as `declare -A`.

Comment: Nice detail: Bash version check at the top. Working code over documentation... :)